# Trying to find the file that called my java application once turn into an .exe and used as default application for an extension

Tags: java, file, exe

I am building an parallax editor in java. I have created my own file format (.plax) using JSON so I can then associate that file format to my tool (converted from .jar to .exe).

I can now launch that file directly in my editor (using the launch with... in windows). Problem is I can't find that file path then in my code, so i can't properly load it!

I tried Launcher_Editor.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().toString() but this only return the .exe used, not my .plax

And 
new File("").getAbsolutePath(). It does give me the right folder, but it does not give me my file.

How could I find the name of the file i just launch using my .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out all the info you need is in the arg[] in the main fonction !

```
public static void main (String[] arg)
{
    if(arg.length > 0)
        path = arg[0] ; 
}
```

Will give you the path you need !